# To get the list of elements after pattern element is matched

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file

```
$ cat a.txt
a_1  
a_2  
a_3  
a_4  
a_5
```

If I search for a_2, I need to get all elements after a_2 including it.
Output expected is

```
a_2
a_3
a_4
a_5
```

Kindly help.

Comment: @fedorqui, not necessarily a duplicate as the other question is specific to sed and this gives answers with different methods.

Comment: @Jidder have you seen the accepted answer in that question? Its solution is both in awk and sed.

Comment: There are many more ways to do this without sed or awk though!

Comment: @Jidder the point of marking as duplicate is to concentrate the knowledge in a point, rather than having good answers spread around different similar questions. So if you feel like adding a new good answer, you can do in the "main" question, that grows as a good point of knowledge.

Comment: @fedorqui Maybe the title of the other question could be changed to not be sed specific then ?

Comment: @fedorqui thanks. This is a duplicate of that question and i have flagged it :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
awk "/a_2/ { flag = 1 }; flag" file
```

Answer (score 3):

Its simple using awk.

```
awk '/a_2/{p=1}p' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Through sed,

```
$ sed -n '/a_2/,/&/p' file
a_2  
a_3  
a_4  
a_5
```

Comment: could you explain the /&/ ? what is the reference behind this `&`, normaly this is the previous matching pattern but here ? and why not a simple `/a_2/,$p` if & is a "unfinding" pattern ?

Comment: i think `/&/` matches upto the last line.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `&` points to whatever `sed` holds in the pattern space. So it searches for `a_2`, finds and puts it in the pattern space and then searches again for `a_2` (referenced by the `&`) but is it never finds it, so it just goes on printing the rest of file

Comment: `sed -n '/a_2/,$p' file`

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way.

```
more +"a_2" file
```